# catch paste events on a dropdown

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to catch paste event occuring on input fields.
It works perfectly on textarea and input but not on dropdowns. Select.
Here is my directive, the console.log is never called.

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ selector: '[catchPasteEvents]' })
export class CatchPastEvent {
  @HostListener('onpaste') onPaste(event) {
    console.log('Paste', event);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `document:onpaste`. Dropdown is not editable and therefore there is nowhere paste event could occur

Answer (score 0):

I created this directive that set a listener on document paste (as suggested by Sergey)  but only when the select element is focused.

```
@Directive({ selector: 'select[selectPaste]' })
export class SelectPasteDirective implements OnDestroy {
  @Output()
  public paste: EventEmitter<ClipboardEvent> = new EventEmitter();

  private listener: (event: ClipboardEvent) => void = this.handlePaste.bind(
    this,
  );

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    document.removeEventListener('paste', this.listener);
  }

  @HostListener('focus')
  public onFocusedItem() {
    document.addEventListener('paste', this.listener);
  }

  @HostListener('blur')
  public onBlurItem() {
    document.removeEventListener('paste', this.listener);
  }

  private handlePaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
    this.paste.emit(event);
  }
}
```